# Paypal Drop-Down Menu Rendering Individually

Tags: forms, paypal, drop-down-menu

my paypal drop-down button is not showing up as a drop down, rather it is showing up as individual boxes.

you can see here:http://www.mattemig.net/store/

code below

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" /> <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FUT8A68TBGR9Y" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size" />Size</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0"> <option value="3 Link (11&quot;)">3 Link (11") </option> </select> <select name="os0"> <option value="4 Link (11&quot;)">4 Link (11") </option> </select> <select name="os0"> <option value="3 Link (9&quot;)">3 Link (9")</option> </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Base Color" />Base Color</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os1"> <option value="Hot Pink">Hot Pink </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Ruby Red">Ruby Red </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Tangerine">Tangerine </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Emerald Green">Emerald Green </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Blue Royal">Blue Royal </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Pure Purple">Pure Purple </option> </select> <select name="os1"> <option value="Midnight Black">Midnight Black </option> </select></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your select options are appearing in their own `select`. Change this to a single `<select>` instead.

E.g., for the 'Size', from:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size" />Size</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0"> <option value="3 Link (11&quot;)">3 Link (11") </option> </select> <select name="os0"> <option value="4 Link (11&quot;)">4 Link (11") </option> </select> <select name="os0"> <option value="3 Link (9&quot;)">3 Link (9")</option> </select></td>
```

To:

```
 <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size" />Size</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="os0"> 
    <option value="3 Link (11&quot;)">3 Link (11") </option> 
    <option value="4 Link (11&quot;)">4 Link (11") </option> 
    <option value="3 Link (9&quot;)">3 Link (9")</option>
    </select></td>
```